# Partition into subgroups

Tags: combinatorics

In a class of 7 boys and 8 girls, how many ways are there to partition the class into 4 mutually disjoint unlabelled subgroups such that each of the subgroup has at least one girl and that the girls A and B will not belong to the same group?

Answer (score 0):

First lets see how to partition the girls. They need to be in four sets since each set must have at least one girl.

We seperate into three cases:

Case 1 is when girl $A$ is not the only girl in her group. In this case we first seperate all girls except $A$ in $7 \brace 4$  ways(stirling coefficient of the second kind). This is because $A$ is not the only girl in her group, so every group must contain at least one of the $7$ girls that are not $A$. After doing this there will be four groups into which $A$ can be put. However one of those groups has $B$, so we can't pick that one. But there are three options. Therefore there are $3  {{7} \brace 4}$ ways to do it.

Case 2: girl $A$ is alone. Then we seperate the remaining girls in $7 \brace 3$ ways.

Therefore there are $3  {{7} \brace 4}+ {7\brace 3}$ ways to seperate the girls into $4$ subgroups.

After the girls have been seperate we proceed to seperate the boys, but this is easy because now the subgroups are "labelled" since the girls that are allready in them distinguish them. So there are $4^7$ ways to assign the boys.

Thus the final answer is $4^7(3  {{7} \brace 4}+ {7\brace 3})=(16384)(3(350)+301)=22,134,784$

Comment: I was unfamiliar with this Stirling Coefficient of the Second Kind.  So, any time you are asked how many ways can you divide up $n$ unique objects into $k$ nonempty subgroups, the answer is $n \choose k$?

Comment: yeah, but in this case there where special restrictions, but yes. that is what the Stirling coefficient counts. They are not very easy to compute. There is a recursion and a formula for $n\brace k$ which has $k$ terms.

Comment: Remember not to mistake $n \brace k$ with $\binom{n}{k}$. The latter is for binomial coefficients.

Comment: Ah.  I had made that mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the clear explanation, I totally get how to arrange the girls now, however, I am still unclear why the number of ways to assign the boys is $4^7$

Comment: If the girls have already been assigned to the four subgroups these subgroups are now different between each other. So at this point of the construction they are different. Then there are $4$ options to assign boy $1$. There are $4$ options to assign boy $2$, there are $4$ options to assign bou $3$..... Since these decisitions are independent we get there are $\underbrace{4\times 4 \times 4 \dots \times 4}_{\text{7 times}}$ ways to assign the boys.

Comment: oh it makes sense now, thank you!